# How long until back In Review after "Metadata Rejected"?

Tags: ios, ios5, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I submitted my update last Tuesday, and yesterday (Saturday) it went into review, but the metadata was rejected an hour later. I updated the metadata, submitted it again, and now it's been Waiting For Review for almost a day. Throughout other threads I see that normally after you fix the metadata, it goes back to In Review straight away. This is not the case for me. Will I have to wait through the entire review process again?

February 11, 2012 12:41
Waiting For Review

February 11, 2012 12:23
Metadata Rejected

February 11, 2012 12:02
In Review

February 07, 2012 21:36
Waiting For Review

February 07, 2012 21:34
Upload Received

February 07, 2012 21:32
Waiting For Upload

Answer (score 4):

Although WrightsCS may be right, Apple took my app back into Review approximately 24 hours after I submitted the updated metadata. This is around Valentines, so that could affect it. But for any future readers of this question, it took me one day from Metadata Rejected to In Review.

Comment: Just really depends on the load of submissions they receive and the time of year I guess.

Comment: Mine took about 36 hours to get to "In Review" and from there about 1 hour to "Ready For Sale". I had received "Metadata Rejected" on a Saturday night. Maybe the weekend effect! But all in all, looking at the above responses, sounds like it depends on the load of submissions.

Comment: But did you push the "Submit for review" or you just replied at the resolution center?

Answer (score 4):

I send in my app 9 days ago, and after 7 days I got my metadata rejected since I forgot to put a text in my app description.

So I fixed that and send it in again, after 18 hours I put my binary down and uploaded a new one since I had implemented more features. Then after only 4 hours my app got into review and approved same day!

Just wanted to say to those who is interested that uploading a new binary when metadata was rejected doesn't seem to put you last in queue!

Comment: Based on this post I switched my binary when my metadata was rejected. Unfortunately it took an additional 7 days. However it was a week before Labor Day. Interestingly this week I got into review in 2 days. I've never seen it happen that quick in the year and half I've submitted. Maybe because they push through everything before the holidays.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I have seen apps go back into review after about a week or so, even after a metadata update, thats most case scenario. Apple usually knocks out reviews quicker during holidays; Christmas, Valentines, etc. You could wait another few hours, or a few more days, just depending on the load of submissions they receive.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Apple's own instructions are incorrect here, causing additional waiting by sending you to the back of the queue. Clicking "submit for review" marks your binary as "Binary Rejected" in resolution center.

See: http://www.brynbodayle.com/an-easy-mistake-with-itunes-connect-metadata-rejections/

Comment: this one should report to a bug.